# Docker-compose: How to connect to mongo container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run my simple Ruby app in Docker container (I am a Windows 10 user). This is just a bunch of Ruby and bash scripts that operate on Mongo database. I am using `docker-compose` to compose 3 containers - one for mongo database (using official mongo image), one for my app and one to populate the database.

Then I run `docker-compose build` and  `docker-compose up` commands. Mongo wakes up fine and it accepts data import. Then I open another Powershell window and run `docker run -it <name> /bin/bash` to get an interactive shell and run my script. Unfortunately, they can't connect to mongo for some reason.

My connection string looks like this:

`@client = Mongo::Client.new([ 'mongodb:27017' ], :database => 'test')`

I tried different versions of it, like `mongodb`, `mongodb://mongodb:27017`, `mongodb://mongo:27017'` but nothing seems to work. When I run my script it runs for several seconds and then gives an error on the first line where I perform any operation on the database. Mongo doesn't show any connection attempts.

What am I doing wrong?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
```

**Mongo-seed Dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo
COPY test.csv /test.csv
CMD mongoimport --host mongodb -d test -c places --type csv --file /test.csv --headerline
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    tty: true
  mongo-seed:
    build: ./mongo-seed
    links:
      - mongodb
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a docker container to an existing docker network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964748/how-to-add-a-docker-container-to-an-existing-docker-network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of spawning a new container with `docker run` connect to the shell of the already running one with `docker exec -ti <name> bash`. Now you should be able to ping your database with `ping mongodb` or to execute your script.

The reason for this is that the new container you create isn't spawned in the same network as your database.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent so much time trying to figure it out and didn't even think about this command. I'm not a smart man. Thank you once again for your time and help.

Comment: you are smarter than you think. :)